# Use only one part of JWT token after split apache camel

Tags: split, jwt, apache-camel

I have header value as JWT token like "ABC.LMN.XYZ". I want to split it using . and store only LMN part of it to header. Is there any way to do it.

```
<split>
   <tokenize headerName="JWTToken" token="\."/>
   <to uri="log:output?showAll=true" />
</split>
```

Comment: Why would you want to do it? How will you be able to verify the contents of the JWT if you don't send the header and signature parts to the recipient?

Comment: I just want to split token "ABC.LMN.XYZ" and use it in same route. Dont want to go to different route.

Comment: I could able to split and use token in same route using groovy script.

Answer (score 0):

```
 .setBody(simple("${body.split(\\.)[1]}"))
            .unmarshal().base64()
```

java dsl here u must add base64 data format

https://camel.apache.org/components/3.7.x/dataformats/base64-dataformat.html

Comment: base64 is for decode. I could able to filter the values using CamelSplitIndex now but not able to set values into header which can be accessed outside split.